# Why does the solaris-8 "scadm shownetwork" command show a different IP address that the one that is actually configured?

Tags: solaris, administration

When I run the *scadm* command, the IP Address is different than the one I have configured on my server:

```
55 /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210/sbin> uname -a
SunOS UI1 5.8 Generic_108528-29 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210
56 /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210/sbin> ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=1000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
bge0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet ***.***.***.*** netmask ffffe000 broadcast ***.***.***.255
        ether 0:3:ba:8a:28:d1
57 /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210/sbin> ./scadm shownetwork
IP Address: 192.168.132.2
Gateway address: 192.168.132.2
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Ethernet address: 00:03:ba:8a:28:da
58 /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210/sbin> cat /etc/inet/hosts
#
# Internet host
#
127.0.0.1       localhost
***.***.***.***    aaaaa
```

The IP Address in */etc/inet/hosts* and the one shown by *ifconfig -a* are correct. The one shown by *scadm shownetwork* is incorrect. Why?

Comment: `scadm` is showing your the ALOM network address, not the primary server network address.

Comment: Stephan -- that is the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise servers, such as the Sun server, tend to have an "out of band" (OOB) management port.  On older machines this was just a serial port, directly connected to the console.

On more modern machines (such as those created in this century!) this port evolved into a "lights out management" port, allowing for more functionality.  On your SunFire machine this is the ALOM port, and it has its own network connection and its own IP address.  Even if the main machine is turned off, the ALOM port is still active and can be used to power on.

The `scadm` command is used to manage the ALOM port.

So what you are seeing is the IP address of the ALOM port, and not the IP address of the server itself.